# Ruby on Rails error "cannot load such file -- less"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, web

I am fairly new to `ruby on rails`, I have been trying to use `twitter-bootstrap` as an asset, so I have included it in my Gemfile, bundled and it installs successfully. However I have noticed that it relies on certain dependencies that are not shown when I do the "bundle" command.

The dependences it needs

```
(1) Libv8
(2) Less
(3) Less-rails
```

Error message:

```
cannot load such file -- less
  (in c:/Sites/todo/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less)

[code]

Extracted source (around line #8):

5:   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
6:     <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
7:   <![endif]-->
8:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
9:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
10:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
11:   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

[/code]

Trace
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:8:in     `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__560528188_27183396'
app/controllers/lists_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```

I have noticed a lot of answers to this very question already, and have chosen the obvious solutions, but somehow I still get stuck, and would really appreciate some guidance.

Comment: What version of twitter bootstrap are you using?

Comment: I am using twitter bootstrap version 2.1.9

Comment: Also Rails version  'rails', '3.2.9'

Answer (score 89, accepted):

I guess you are using sass instead of LESS.

Have you tried the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem?

```
gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails"
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
```

https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails

Comment: This is the gem that i am using currently, however i dont have the gem  therubyracer or less-rails

Comment: I guess that's it... I've followed the guide on the link and it worked fine.
Like I've said, rails uses SASS instead of LESS. That's why the other two gems are required. (I am using rails 3)

Answer (score 27):

I simply needed to restart my server.

I had added the three gems listed above (`less-rails`, `therubyracer`, and `twitter-bootstrap-rails`, with *Rails 3.2.13*) while my local server was running, resulting in the problem seen above. So once I shut it down and restarted it again, everything loaded well.

Comment: then why didnt you pick this as the correct answer?

Comment: @CodeBiker, yeah a restart was required for my rails app as well.

Answer (score 7):

You have to either update `therubyracer` or downgrade the `twitter-bootstrap-rails` gem down to version 2.1.7 which is the last known version that didn't have this issue.

Run either `bundle update` to update your gems or in your `Gemfile` make your twitter-bootstrap-rails gem look like this:

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', '2.1.7'
```

Take a look at this issue:

https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues/465

This issue started happening on versions after 2.1.7 on `twitter-bootstrap-rails`.

Comment: I try to install libv8 but it keeps failing, and the therubyracer depends on it, and also the "less" depends on the "therubyracer"

Comment: @NicolasBrown try uninstalling and re-installing... ``gem uninstall libv8`` then ``bundle install`` will detect the dependency of therubyracer and will install libv8. And restart your server, as was mentioned in another post.

Answer (score 4):

If you are getting it under Windows this should help you 
[therubyracer_for_windows](https://github.com/hiranpeiris/therubyracer_for_windows)

It helped me

Comment: Does not exist anymore (404 not found)

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you are on windows ... there is no libv8 for windows and no binary therubyracer because it depends on libv8