# therubyracer not installing on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rubygems, therubyracer

When attempting to install gem I am getting following error

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\mg>gem install therubyracer
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20150527-5032-1urwkwd.
rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.7/ext/libv8/b
uilder.rb:68:in `setup_python!': libv8 requires python 2 to be installed in orde
r to build, but it is currently not available (RuntimeError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.
7/ext/libv8/builder.rb:52:in `block in build_libv8!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.
7/ext/libv8/builder.rb:49:in `chdir'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.
7/ext/libv8/builder.rb:49:in `build_libv8!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.
7/ext/libv8/location.rb:24:in `install!'
        from extconf.rb:7:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1
.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.7 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86
-mingw32/2.1.0/libv8-3.16.14.7/gem_make.out
```

I have tried adding this in Gemfile

```
gem 'therubyracer',
gem 'less-rails
```

Tried

```
gem uninstall libv8
gem install therubyracer -v=0.10.1
```

Everything above failed and therubyracer never installed.

Comment: ... Is Python 2 installed?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356450/therubyracer-gem-on-windows

Comment: yes I have python2.7 installed and working fine at command prompt

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the `rubyracer` gem does not work on Windows. See this

https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8/issues/133

Comment: I have removed both gems 'therubyracer', 'less-rails' coz I don't need them, my bundle got installed successfully but getting errors saying "LoadError - cannot load such file -- less"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888381/ruby-on-rails-error-cannot-load-such-file-less