# RubyOnRails- How to bundle?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, windows-7-x64

I am trying to install all dependencies via following command:

```
bundle install
```

It gave me following error:

```
An error occurred while installing libv8 <3.16.14.13>, and bundle cannot continue.
Make sure  that 'gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.13' ' succeeds before bundling.
```

Then from this link:

[Error installing libv8: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19673714/rails-gem-install-error-error-installing-libv8-error-failed-to-build-gem-nati)

I found this solution:

```
gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.13' -- --with-system-v8
```

It then installed the `libv8`

Then again I ran the command:

```
bundle install
```

Now its giving me following error:

```
An error occurred while installing therubyracer <0.12.2>, and bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that 'gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.2' ' succeeds before bundling.
```

I tried deleting `therubyracer` from gem file and then run the command but i am getting the same error.

Please guide me.

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are using Windows 7 , then prepare yourself:

Unfortunately, there's no know way of installing that gem on Windows:
Linked question: [therubyracer not installing on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30487976/therubyracer-not-installing-on-windows)

This is one of many things that made me change to Linux.

**EDIT**

There is a workaround but its from 4 years ago so , I hope this will work:
https://github.com/eakmotion/therubyracer_for_windows

**EDIT 2 - About middleman**

Did you install the DevKit for RubyInstaller?.
Here you have the documentation of the gem with the installation steps:
https://github.com/middleman/middleman

**EDIT 3**
Check this one. There are others with the same issue (of course) and they managed to "solved" it using it:
https://github.com/jawwadzafar/middleman-boilerplate

Comment: So is there any workaround that I neglect this dependency and install other dependencies. . and would then the project work properly?

Comment: What are you trying to install?. Those should be dependencies of others. I'm looking into my projects on Windows and i dont have them. EDITED: Ok, nothing. You are trying to install libv8 right? Check my updated answer.

Comment: I am trying to run middleman server by this command: middleman server. but it give me active support error and suggestion to run bundle install

Comment: It's true. Windows + Ruby/Rails is just endless tears

Comment: Yes I have installed DevKit.

Comment: I'm glad that i was of help. Good luck following the hard way of the samu....I mean, the Ruby/Windows.